# Burdens of working as an airline pilot

Tags: career

Every job in every industry has some "pressure", "stress", or "burdens" for that job. Being a PPL feels free, but I'm paying for flying. Working as a pilot, I get paid for flying. BUT, before I decide I want to join this industry, what are the burdens that an airline pilot has to face routinely? Does it vary if you're working for a small regional airline vs major international airlines?

Comment: You forgot the word "poorly" in there somewhere.

Comment: @CGCampbell yea? where?

Comment: I suppose @CGCampbell meant as in "poorly paid". I understood from other questions on this site that in North America wages are currently low especially in regional airlines. Situation differs a lot across the world so you can probably get good money in Middle East or Asia (if you can get at least 737 or A320 rating and are willing to move or live away).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is a very broad topic and is heavily opinion based.*

Vast majority of commercial pilots do love flying and that's the reason they go through the *abuse* by airlines. **All** GA pilots also love flying but either cannot afford the abuse or don't have time for it, so they just pay to satisfy this hobby.

So to answer your question, some of the burdens are:

- High costs of training
- Waiting a long time (2 years or more on occasions) before getting hired by an airline
- Very low salaries in the beginning (several years)
- Losing seniority (very often) when you go to another carrier
- Staying away from home a lot
- Very unstable industry
- Many pilots eventually get bored and frustrated (regardless of initial enthusiasm)

Having said that, there are many many great benefits, too. The bottom line is that people only get into this career if they love it deeply.

The question you have to ask yourself is: *Am I willing to undergo this trouble for my passion?*

---

**P.S.:** The above holds true for the airlines and pilots in the US.

Comment: I believe it should be mentioned this is specific to North America. Middle East and Asia have shortage of pilots and therefore offer better wages and conditions. I heard 2nd-hand about pilots from Europe going to Middle East or Asia for much better money and in Europe the wages are a lot better than US.

Comment: @JanHudec True. I looked at FO monthly benefits for [Etihad](http://www.etihad.com/en/careers/flight-operations/first-officer-b777/). US Airlines also pay the same but only annually.

Comment: Two more downside items: the possibility of losing your career because of medical problems and, if flying international routes, the stress of significant time zone changes.

Comment: The airline industry is projecting a serious pilot shortage in the US. In large part due to the drastically shrinking military pilot pool. Sorry I don't have a link to the article.

Comment: Ditto on "unstable". Never mind market swings, Major airlines must be the most mismanaged businesses ever. Gone are TWA, Pan AM, Eastern, Braniff. The carnage is stunning. Braniff bankrupted itself buying up routes. Carl Icahn was able to shred TWA because it was dying. Next time a major's CEO whines for a handout just say "Southwest". Oh, and unions have participated in the self-flaggelation, according to 1 insider's personal anacdote.

Comment: I know a number of current and former airline pilots and I would add "Stress on relationships".  Some of my airline pilot friends have been through multiple divorces as their spouses have drifted away and found other interests. No doubt this is partially a result of the "time away from home" item, but needs to be mentioned since it can have a direct effect on one's current and future earnings, ability to retire, retirement lifestyle, etc.

Comment: I always thought that the high divorce rate was due to the "fooling around with the flight attendants" problem. Now that the average age of flight attendants has skyrocketed, maybe that is no longer an issue.

Comment: Being an airline pilot in Europe myself, I can underline the above mentioned. The "work" itself is the way of becoming an airline pilot, not the flying later on. You need a long breath if it isn't successful at the first place. Flying is a service, so be prepared to spend your Off-days when others are at work. Or to leave the house when others are still asleep...

Comment: Pilots need to fly a certain number of hours each year if they want to maintain their flying privileges. Due to this, nowadays, some pilots pay airlines to hire them, so that they can fly. In France there even are petitions being created to make this practice illegal.