# What is a typical working day like for an Australian airline pilot?

Tags: airline-operations, airlines, airline-pilot, australia

What is it like working for a domestic airline in Australia (e.g. Virgin, Regional Express, etc)?

Obviously we're all here because we're interested in flying, but as for the practical aspects of being employed in the airline industry I'm trying to get an idea of some of the following:

- What does a typical working day look like and what are the hours?
- What are airlines like as employers?
- What is the best thing (or things) about your job?
- What is the worst thing (or things) about your job?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very open-ended question as airlines' jobs vary greatly from country to country, and what is true for one country would be very different in another.

Comment: @Farhan I've narrowed the scope of the question to Australia.

Comment: Somewhat similar to this question: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/burdens-of-working-as-an-airline-pilot

Comment: Australia? Wake up, try not to get eaten by a snake. Get dressed, try not to be bitten by a spider. Go out to the car, dodge a crocodile...... Etc

Comment: @JonStory You forgot to dodge the dropbear, feed the bunyip and ride the kangaroo to work.

Comment: Can somebody please ask `What is the typical working day of a Russian pilot?` so I can say "not to be confused with ..."

Comment: I'm surprised no-one chose to answer this. I think it's a useful question. So what if it's opinion based, that's the point of getting a few different answers. @usernumber - thanks for linking that other question, it's the one useful response to my question.

Comment: @MarkyMark It's not "so what" that it's opinion-based. Stack Exchange's system of supposedly objective voting on answers falls apart once the answers cannot be judged objectively. How is one answer to "what is the best thing(s) about your job?" more correct than another? On what criteria do you select a "best" or "most useful" answer to accept?

Comment: The question is a bit open-ended, but a typical day for a domestic short-haul pilot on one-day trips might be 2 x 4.5 hr transcon sectors or  2 x return east coast 1.5 hr sectors (6 hours stick time). For multi-day trips, the average stick time might be about 5 hrs each day. It really depends on the patterns. What are airlines like as employers? The answer depends on your own point of view, but in general, things are highly professional ( for both employer and employee), compared to many other places. Safety is a big deal in Australia - both employer and employee take it very seriously.