# Is being a pilot stressful or hard?

Tags: commercial-aviation, general-aviation, canada

As a Canadian teenager hoping to become a commercial pilot, I'd like to know how hard it actually is to live the life of a pilot. I've heard from some people that the hours can be pretty gruesome, which is obviously a little off-putting. Are you able to maintain a relationship?Are the hours off-duty at home plentiful enough or few and far between? Is the pay worth it? Do you get vacation days and/or sick days like any other job? Any details on the life of a pilot and whether or not you'd suggest it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Scheduling varies *wildly* depending on the type of operation: commuter vs. mainline domestic vs. short-haul int'l vs. long-haul int'l, pax vs. cargo, scheduled vs. unscheduled vs. charter vs. fractional vs. corporate.  And that's not even counting miscellaneous ops (part 91, as well as vertical reference and external load helicopter flying)

Comment: Hi Devin, welcome to Aviation.StackExchange!  Your question is one that a lot of people have, but I feel that it's too broad for this site, and it's going to attract a lot of opinion-based answers rather than the kind of fact-based answers that we're looking for.  Can you narrow your question down any?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Burdens of working as an airline pilot](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/burdens-of-working-as-an-airline-pilot)